# Android Studio and Material Design

Tags: android

I have been writing Android apps that target KitKat and using the Design Support Library for Material Design widgets (floating action button, NavigationView, etc).

Today I started a new App and got the go ahead to set the min version as Lolipop (Api 22).

I expected to see these new widgets in the Android Studio "Design Palette", but they're not there. I made sure to select API 22 in the dropdown menu at the top, but I am still not seeing these new widgets.

Is there something that I need to do that I am unaware of? I would assume that the "Design" view, would have these as selectable widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not rely on the `IDE` or `Android Studio "Design Palette"`, use the Android Docs. What widgets are you looking for that aren't there? Those widgets are the widgets that come in the standard `android.jar`. The "`floating action button, NavigationView, etc`" come from extra support libraries.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like what you are saying is that I won't necessarily see all the Widgets in the Android Studio palette. That's good to know. I thought I wasn't doing something that I needed to.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying.